# How to set UIScreen Brightness Using UISlider in iOS4 from Setting.bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am working one Feature of setting Brightness of mainscreen
i search lots of googling got one code.

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
float fBrightness = slider.value;
[[UIScreen mainScreen]setBrightness:fBrightness];
```

But this code is worked Only iOS5 not in iOS4 when i am using this code in my apps i got warning and my app crash

```
 warning: 'UIScreen' may not respond to '-setBrightness:'
```

so please anyone help me how to empliments this feature in iOS4 
thank you

**EDIT:-(Solution)**

```
-(void)ActionBrightness{


    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];    //slidervalue from setting.bundle
    float values = [defaults2 floatForKey:@"slider_preference"];
    NSLog(@"value of slider %f",values);

    //if(polygonView == nil){
    polygonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 0, 0, 500, 500)];

    //add code to customize, e.g. polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    polygonView.userInteractionEnabled  = NO;

    if(values < 0.1){
        polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];//DARK_VIEW;
        polygonView.alpha = 0.4;
    }
    else if((values < 0.2) && (values > 0.1)) {
        polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];//DARK_VIEW;
        polygonView.alpha = 0.2;
    }
    else if((values < 0.3) && (values > 0.2)) {
        polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];//DARK_VIEW;
        polygonView.alpha = 0.1;
    }
    else if((values < 0.4) && (values > 0.3)) {
        polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];//DARK_VIEW;
        polygonView.alpha = 0.0;
    }
    else if((values < 0.5) && (values > 0.4)) {
        polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//DARK_VIEW;
        polygonView.alpha = 0.1;
    }
    else if((values < 0.6) && (values > 0.5)) {
        polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//DARK_VIEW;
        polygonView.alpha = 0.2;
    }



    NSLog(@"vakdfjkdf %f",values );
    [self.view addSubview:polygonView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:polygonView];
    [polygonView release];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah you can do that by adding a blackView on your view and change its alpha based on the slider value .. it will looks like you are changing the brightness.

Comment: thank  you i will impliments this but is there any other way to implements this stuff or not..?

Comment: in iOS 4 this is the easy way to do it .. i don't think there is other ways to do that.