# How to set brightness using phonegap?

Tags: android, html, cordova, brightness

While developing applications using HTML5 and Phonegap, is there any way to access or set the brightness of phone (Android)?

Comment: i am not working in phonegame but in iphone i set like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783513/how-to-set-uiscreen-brightness-using-uislider-in-ios4-from-setting-bundle might be its logic helps to you

Comment: Might be that you need to write a plugin to phonegap. You really do need to write the FAQ though, this is a very low effort question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

through phonegap you can not do that straight forward way. You Need to use `IHardwareService` interface for this ( in native way ).

This is not possible via current phonegap API. We need to develop some plugins which would do that. I think such plugins are not available currently.