# How to change brightness of an Video or Image using UISlider on run time(Camera) in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, xcode4.5

```
-(IBAction)changeslidervalue:(id)sender
{
NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];   
float values = [defaults2 floatForKey:@"slider_preference"];
NSLog(@"value of slider %f",values);

if(imageView == nil){
imageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 0, 0, 500, 500)];


imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled  = NO;
}
if(values < 0.1){
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    imageView.alpha = 0.4;
}
else if((values < 0.2) && (values > 0.1)) {
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    imageView.alpha = 0.2;
}
else if((values < 0.3) && (values > 0.2)) {
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    imageView.alpha = 0.1;
}
else if((values < 0.4) && (values > 0.3)) {
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    imageView.alpha = 0.0;
}
else if((values < 0.5) && (values > 0.4)) {
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    imageView.alpha = 0.1;
}
else if((values < 0.6) && (values > 0.5)) {
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    imageView.alpha = 0.2;
}

NSLog(@" Brightness is %f",values );
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

}

I am using this code for click the camera button(Run time)then change the brightness of take the photo or Video.
   Please Someone help me or solve the my issue.

Comment: you are using code from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783513/how-to-set-uiscreen-brightness-using-uislider-in-ios4-from-setting-bundle as my quiestion but its image camera or video brightness its a defoult seting above code working for particular Viewcontroller